# Existence of weak homotopy equivalence not a symmetric relation

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am having trouble coming up with an example of spaces where there exists a weak homotopy equivalence in one direction but not the other. Any hints or references are greatly appreciated!

Note: This is an instance of stagnating autodidactic studying, hence no home-work tag.

Answer (score 9):

The circle $S^1$ is weakly equivalent to the so-called pseudocircle $\mathbb{S}$ (see  [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocircle)), and the weak equivalence goes $S^1 \to \mathbb{S}$. Any map $\mathbb{S}\to S^1$ induces the trivial map on $\pi_1$.

There are many more examples:

As shown by McCord ([Singular homology groups and homotopy groups of finite topological spaces](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/mathscinet-getitem?mr=196744)), any finite simplicial complex is weakly equivalent to a finite topological space.

Comment: This is a cool answer!