# How to show given space is not simply connected?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

> Let $X=\{p,q,r,s\}$ with  topology induced by basis $\{p\}$,$\{r\}$,$\{p,q,r\}$, $\{p,r,s\}$. Then $X$ is not simply connected.

My Attempt:

$\{p\}$ is open set and $\{q\}$ is closed set.

Define $\phi:[0,1]\to X$, where

$$\phi(x)=\begin{cases} q & x=0,1,\\ p & x\in (0,1). \end{cases}.$$

$\phi$ is a continuous loop. But how to show it is not homotopic to constant?

Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Alternatively, can you find the fundamental group of $X$?

Comment: You should try with a slight different curve. There are only two points you can go continuously to, from p, but you can't go from either of them to the other.

Comment: @Math1000 How to find fundamental group using just basis ? I tried to use Van Kampen theorem But unable to do? Please can you give me some hint

Comment: If you know the groupoid version of van Kampen then you can use it.  If not then you probably have to use covering spaces.

Comment: This question is probably a duplicate though, let me see if I can find a link.

Comment: The question I linked is different, but my answer there answers your question just as well (by constructing a nontrivial covering space of $X$, or alternatively by constructing a weak homotopy equivalence $S^1\to X$).

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161580/an-interesting-topological-space-with-4-elements for related discussion and references.